# nftw total or available number of file handles

Tags: c, unix, posix

`nftw` wants a parameter for the number of file handles to use. I've seen a couple of examples specifying this as 20 (this is the POSIX guaranteed minimum? but one could also use `getrlimit` or `sysconf` to get the actual available number). Should this not be specified as 17 because three file handles are already used for stdin/out/err? Or am I misunderstanding how it works? (Similarly if we get the actual available number with `getrlimit` or `sysconf`, should we subtract 3 before passing the parameter?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of file descriptors is the total number of file descriptors the process can have. Functions like `sysconf` doesn't know if some of them are already used or not. You can test this by opening a number of files, and `sysconf` should return the same value both before and after.

It's probably a good idea to subtract 3 for the standard file descriptors, and maybe a couple of more just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving at least three file descriptors open for stdin, stdout, and stderr sounds like excellent advice. Further, you might have a descriptor or two open for your own needs. A quick scan of my system shows a range between `0` and `109` open descriptors, with `4` being quite common.